# Plumber not working?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var config = require('./gulp.config')();
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({ lazy: true });
gulp.task('styles', function () {
    log('Compiling Less --> CSS');
    return gulp
        .src(config.less)
        .pipe($.plumber())
        .pipe($.less())
        .pipe($.autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 3 versions', '> 5%'] }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.styles));
});

gulp.task('less-watcher', function () {
    gulp.watch([config.less], ['styles']);
});
```

when I create an error on .less file I receive the error but the watcher hangs and if I fix the error i need to restart the watcher. I thought this was handled by plumber... ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `return` keyword. remove it to allow plumber works fine!

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
     log('Compiling Less --> CSS');
     gulp.src(config.less)
         .pipe($.plumber())
         .pipe($.less())
         .pipe($.autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 3 versions', '> 5%'] }))
         .pipe(gulp.dest(config.styles)); });
```